# Order array of objects given an order array on Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using Google's directions API to get an optimized routes list given several points. It returns an array with the right order for the points:

```
[4, 0, 6, 7, 1, 3, 5, 2]
```

I want to use that array to order my points as well, which is an array of objects:

```
[obj0, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6, obj7]
```

And get as a result:

```
[obj4, obj0, obj6, obj7, obj1, obj3, obj5, obj2]
```

What can I do in order to accomplish this?

Comment: use `Array.sort`

Comment: I think you mean to map the array order to the objects, it going to be something like

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the function `map`.

```js
var indexes = [4, 0, 6, 7, 1, 3, 5, 2],
    objs = ['obj0', 'obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3', 'obj4', 'obj5', 'obj6', 'obj7'],
    result = indexes.map(i => objs[i]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//googleArray = [4, 0, 6, 7, 1, 3, 5, 2]
var myArray = [];
myOldArray = [obj0, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6, obj7];
for(var i in googleArray){
    myArray[i] = myOldArray[googleArray[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the order array, building up a new array as you go:

```
var orders = [4, 0, 6, 7, 1, 3, 5, 2];
var objects = [obj0, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6, obj7];

var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
    output.push(objects[orders[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function orderArr(reference, arrayToOrder) {
    var ordArr = [];
    referenceArr.forEach((e, i) => {
        ordArr.push(arrayToOrder[e])
    })
    return ordArr;
}
```

You have a lot of options, haha!

But the @Ele answer is the best one.